# WooCommerce: Old deleted item comes back when trying to change the quantity of other item in cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have created a custom popup cart using `WooCommerce`. It has functionalities like

- Decrease a product
- Increase a product
- Remove a product
  [image: Cart]

When I remove the product from the top it goes away. I am using this logic to do that using `AJAX`.

```php
public function remove_item($key)
{
    $this->refresh();
    $remove = $this->woocommerce->cart->remove_cart_item($key);
    $this->woocommerce->cart->calculate_totals();
    if ($remove) {
        $this->refresh();
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now I decrease the remaining item, from quantity 2 to 1. What I get back is the already deleted comes back with 1 quantity and the present item is set to 1.

```php
public function set_item_quantity($key, $quantity)
{
    if (!is_numeric($quantity)) {
        return;
    }

    $job = $this->woocommerce->cart->set_quantity($key, $quantity, true);
    $this->woocommerce->cart->calculate_totals();

    if ($job) {
        $this->refresh();
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is what `refresh` method looks like.

```php
public function refresh()
{
    $woocommerce = \WC();
    $this->cart = $woocommerce->cart;
    $this->woocommerce = $woocommerce;
    $this->woocommerce->cart->calculate_totals();
}
```

This isn't a cache issue, as I have removed my cache plugin and it still gives me issues. The same doesn't happen when the cart has just one product.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: There are many types of caches built in wp and woo. There is cart session cashe  otherwise if you close the window your cart will be empty if you visit the website again. So i think your scripts are not updating that.